# Preventing Windows shutdown in Rust

Tags: winapi, rust, shutdown, windows-messages, system-shutdown

I'm trying to require a user to confirm a Windows shutdown while my program is performing critical tasks.

In order to do this, I want to listen for a [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) message (in a seperate thread from the main program).

If this message is received, I'm calling [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) to prevent the shutdown.

You'll find my current implementation below.

Since the Win32 API also states that [only visible windows are allowed to block shutdowns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutdown-changes-for-windows-vista), i made the window that listens to the messages visible once a WM_QUERYENDSESSION is received.

My issue is, that the program does not seem to receive any WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages ever.
Logging all messages did reveal it receiving other messages, as expected, as well as messages 799 and 800, which i could not find in any [Windows Messages Documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages).

I'm greatful for any help you can give me, as I feel very lost here.

My current implementation:

```
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::{LPARAM, LRESULT, UINT, WPARAM, HINSTANCE};
use winapi::shared::windef::{HWND, HMENU};
use winapi::um::winuser::{
    CreateWindowExW, DefWindowProcW, DispatchMessageW, GetMessageW, PostQuitMessage,
    RegisterClassW, ShowWindow, TranslateMessage, MSG, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    WM_CREATE, WM_DESTROY, WM_QUERYENDSESSION, SW_HIDE, SW_SHOW,
    WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
    ShutdownBlockReasonCreate, ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy,
};

pub fn start_preventing_shutdown() {
    let class_name = "ProgramNameClass";
    let window_name = "ProgramName";
    let hinstance = null_mut();
    let hwnd_parent = null_mut();
    let hmenu = null_mut();
    let hwnd = create_window(
        class_name, window_name, hinstance, hwnd_parent, hmenu, SW_HIDE,
    );

    let mut msg: MSG = Default::default();
    loop {
        unsafe {
            GetMessageW(&mut msg, hwnd, 0, 0);
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }
}

fn create_window(
    class_name: &str,
    window_name: &str,
    hinstance: HINSTANCE,
    hwnd_parent: HWND,
    hmenu: HMENU,
    n_cmd_show: i32,
) -> HWND {
    let wnd_class = winapi::um::winuser::WNDCLASSW {
        style: 0,
        lpfnWndProc: Some(wnd_proc),
        hInstance: hinstance,
        lpszClassName: class_name.encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr(),
        cbClsExtra: 0,
        cbWndExtra: 0,
        hIcon: null_mut(),
        hCursor: null_mut(),
        hbrBackground: null_mut(),
        lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
    };
    unsafe {
        RegisterClassW(&wnd_class);
        let hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
            WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, // set the window style to WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
            class_name.encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr(),
            window_name.encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr(),
            0,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            hwnd_parent,
            hmenu,
            hinstance,
            null_mut(),
        );
        ShowWindow(hwnd, n_cmd_show); // hide the window when it is created
        hwnd
    }
}

unsafe extern "system" fn wnd_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: UINT,
    w_param: WPARAM,
    l_param: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {

    match msg {
        WM_CREATE => {
            0
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(hwnd); // remove the shutdown block when the application is closing
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            0
        }
        WM_QUERYENDSESSION => {
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW); // show the window when the system is trying to shut down
            ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hwnd, "Preventing shutdown".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr()); // call ShutdownBlockReasonCreate before returning from the message handler
            1
        }
        _ => {
            DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, w_param, l_param)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the window receive a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message if it isn't hidden?

Comment: Wouldn't `"Preventing shutdown".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>().as_ptr()` create a dangling pointer? The vector needs to outlive the pointer.

Comment: I also don't think `encode_utf16()` nul-terminates the generated string. I think you need to do something like this: `"Preventing shutdown\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>()` and you then need to store this somewhere that will outlive winapi's use of the pointer.

Comment: The [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate has the convenient [`w!`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/macro.w.html) macro to generate a UTF-16 encoded, null-terminated character string literal (with `'static` lifetime).

Comment: @IInspectable Nice, that is probably the better way to go then.